# Time complexity for while loops using modulo

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, analysis, modulo

I need help with finding out the time complexity of the first and second loop(the nested for-while loop), I'm not so sure of my answers:

**for the first loop: O(log n)**

**for the second loop: O(sqrt(n) logn)**

The Code:

```
public static int findLength(int n){

        int length = 0;
        //FIRST LOOP
        while (n%2==0){
            length++;
            n /= 2;
        }

        //SECOND LOOP
        for (int i = 3; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i+= 2) {

            while (n%i == 0) {
                length++;

                n /= i;

            }
        }


        if (n > 2)
            length++;

          return length;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**FIRST LOOP**

- *First Extreme*: `n` is *odd*

  - loop doesn't run
  - Time: `O(1)`
- *Second Extreme*: `n` is *power of 2*

  - loop runs maximum no of times (with respect to different values of `n`)
  - Time: `O(log n)`

Overall time complexity: **`O(log n)`**

---

**SECOND LOOP**

- *First Extreme*: `n` is *prime*

  - *Nested* `while` loop doesn't run at all
  - Time: `O(sqrt(n))`
- *Second Extreme*: `n = (p1 ^ q1) * (p2 ^ q2) * .. * (pn ^ qn)`, where `p1, p2 .. pn` are *primes* (generalization of *first extreme*)

  - Total number of operations (excluding *loop counters* / *test expressions*): `q1 + q2 + ... + qn`
  - Time: `O(log n)`

Overall time complexity: **`O(sqrt(n))`**

Comment: Note that above analysis assumes that the value `Math.sqrt(n)` is **cached by optimizer** and not evaluated in every *iteration*. Otherwise the complexity would be `O(sqrt(n) * log n)` like you figured (because [`Math.sqrt(n)` takes `log(n)` time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23103847/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-the-following-function))

Comment: may i ask why you excluded the loop increments and test expressions in the outer for loop? but thank you for the explanation i really understood it. peace

Comment: my guess is that when the INNER loop doesn't run, the steps taken by the OUTER loop will only be taken into account, but when the INNER loop runs, only the number of steps of the innermost loop would be taken into account even though the INNER loop may not run at some iterations of the OUTER loop

Comment: In asymptotic analysis of run-time (or space) of a piece of code, we are only interested in determining the amount of time (or space) spent on the **real work**. Loop counters / test expressions are therefore left out. It is even common to ignore overhead of recursive calls. But even if you consider them, the **result won't change** [increment, assignment & comparison are O(1); modulo % is O(no-of-digits) = O(log n), which becomes O(1) for numbers having fixed no of bits]. So it just eases the task at hand without affecting the result (Asymptotic analysis already relies on **approximation**)